# How to call java class from jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have written simple java program:

```
package bsh;

import test.Testclass;

public class Whatever {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Testclass t = new Testclass();
        System.out.println(t.squareIt(8));
    }
}
```

```
package test;

public class Testclass {

    public Testclass(){
    }

    public int squareIt(int i){
        return i*i;
    }
}
```

I have two questions about this java program:

1. How to execute this java program from jmeter?
2. How to call sqaureIt(int i) method from jmeter?

How can i achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute java class from Jmeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768590/how-to-execute-java-class-from-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried main class execution , but i have certainly executed Junit Testcases through Jmeter

Have a look at this doc [Junitsampler tutorial](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from following the tutorial as Sudhakar mentioned...
Your main test case must extend TestCase or some form of it. 
Your test method must begin with the word **test** or use annotations.
Do not use a void main method as in a normal java application. 

It will automatically call and run your method that starts with the name **test**. 

So you could do this:

```
public class Whatever extends TestCase {

    public void testIt() {
        //test code here
        new Testclass().squareIt(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

JMeter is typically used for testing performance on web applications. Correct me if I'm wrong, but unless you plan on converting this into some sort of web app, you should try using [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) to measure your program's performance.