# How to call a method from user created jar using jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a requirement to call one of the method which is present in user created class. Can someone enlighten me/ how can I achieve this?

Please share the detailed steps.

Ex: lets say a `abc.jar` (or `abc.class`) having `x` , `y` & `z` methods having `arg1`, `arg2` & `arg3`.

Requirement:

I want to call `x`, `y` & `z` methods from `abc` class by passing `arg1`, `arg2` & `arg3` values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute java class from Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768590/how-to-execute-java-class-from-jmeter)

Comment: please provide a concrete case how you want to use this class: is it a sampler, a part of your script, or what?

Comment: I want to call one of the method by passing few parameters and it should perform operations defined in it. Can you please elaborate how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Balakrishna,

Place your User created Jar file in "lib/ext" folder of JMeter,
Now using a beanshell sampler you can call those methods ..

import the package name in beanshell sampler.
instantiate an object for the class.
call the methods

[Refer to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdtpM.jpg)

Moreover you may link to follow blog :
https://www.redline13.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your .jar somewhere into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), for example into "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add a [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to your Test Plan and call the method from .jar file as you would do this in Java. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.

Example:

- Given you have the following class:

  ```
  public class abc {
      public String x(String arg1) {
          return "Hello, " + arg1 + " from abc.jar";
      }
  }
  ```
- package it as `abc.jar` and copy the file to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
- Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test Plan and put the following code into "Script" area:

  ```
  def instanceOfAbc = new abc();
  String methodReturnValue = instanceOfAbc.x("Gorantla Balakrishna");
  log.info(methodReturnValue);
  ```
- That's it, `x` method should be executed:

  [image: JMeter call .jar from Groovy]